# Django template -- render a list of dictionaries with incrementing values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Without incrementing a template variable, which would be a hacky way to do it, how can I "remember" which level my subskill variable is at and correctly "increment" the level counter in a Django template?

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this: `[{'level': 0, 'skill': 'style a page using CSS'}, {'level': 0, 'skill': 'download JSFiddle'}, {'level': 1, 'skill': 'learn django'}, {'level': 2, 'skill: 'customize a template'}]`

and I want to render it like this:

[image]

But I can't figure out a way to properly increment a counter variable in a django template.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
{% with level=0 %}
<h1 align="center"> Level: {{level}} </h1>
{% for subskill in subskills %}

  {%if subskill.level > level%}

    <h1 align="center"> Level:{{level|add:1}} </h1>
  {%endif%} ... {%endfor%} {%endwith%}
```

What I have right now will only ever increment level to one, but this increment isn't stored. So it goes Level 0, Level 1, Level 1, Level 1

Comment: I think it would be easier just chaning your input to something like
`{0:[{'skill': 'style a page using CSS'}, {'skill': 'download JSFiddle'}], 1: [{'skill': 'learn django'}], 2: [{'skill: 'customize a template'}]}` where keys of this dictionary are your levels. And then just iterate through dictionary, and do subloop for rendering lists of data

Comment: How do you iterate through this dictionary in a django template? I've tried ```for entry in list... for subskill in list.entry``` but that isn't working

Comment: A for loop counter is no good. I have levels 1-10. And levels can have multiple subskills.

Comment: Okay I was able to iterate using the first comment's structuring with this code ```{% for level, subskill_list in subskills.items%}
    <h1 align="center"> Level: {{level}} </h1>
    {% for subskill in subskill_list %}```

Comment: So, is it working now?

Comment: Yes it is, @SardorbekImomaliev

Comment: make this an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, by changing the structure of my list to look like

`subskills = {0:[{'skill': 'style a page using CSS'}, {'skill': 'download JSFiddle'}], 1: [{'skill': 'learn django'}], 2: [{'skill: 'customize a template'}]}`

pass to the view with

`return render(request, 'subskills.html', {'subskills': subskills})`

and then render in the template with:

`{% for level, subskill_list in subskills.items%} 
       <h1 align="center"> Level: {{level}} </h1> 
           {% for subskill in subskill_list %}
               render subskill here...
           {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter it helped me!

as You replied in the answer:

```
    {% for level, subskill_list in subskills.items%}
        <h1 align="center"> Level: {{level}} </h1>
        {% for subskill in subskill_list %}
            render subskill here...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

It will give again dictionary.
To have Key and values rendered out there,
We may use :

```
    {% for level, subskill_list in subskills.items%}
        <h1 align="center"> Level: {{level}} </h1>
        {% for subskill in subskill_list %}
            {% for first, second in subskill.items %}
                {{ first }}             # Key
                enter code here
                {{ second }}            # Value
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

this first and second will give you extracted Key and Value corresponding to items in dictionaries.